# Sources on preventing someone's marriage to a non-Jew?

Tags: marriage, intermarriage

A close family member is dating a non-Jew very seriously, and I am worried they will get married.

Is there any recommended reading material, that could help me prevent their marriage, or ending the relationship entirely?

Comment: After my editing, why is this question still "on hold"?

Comment: I'm not seeing that there's a request for practical psak here, just recommendations for reading material. || M. Yisrael, try http://preventintermarriage.com/ .